# Nonlinear constraint and product of variables

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I have been asked to add to an existing linear programming model several constraints dealing with ratios among continuous decision variables. An example ratio constraint would be like:

$x_1*x_2 - x_3*x_4 = 0$

They told me to preserve the lineal nature of the problem, so I am trying to find an equivalent linear formulation to the previous type of constraints.

I have tried with Lagrange multipliers, but the system obtained from setting the derivative to zero is not linear. I also tried to do the Relaxation-Linearization Technique on it, but it did not seem to work.

I am stuck at a point where I do not really know if I am misunderstanding these techniques, or facing a problem without an evident solution.

A simplification (real one is bigger) of the problem would be like this:

$min = a1 + a2 + b1 + b2$
$s.t.$
$a1 + b1 - 200 < 0$ 
$a2 + b2 - 200 < 0$ 
$b1 - 80 < 0$ 
$b1 - 60 > 0$ 
$b2 - 30 < 0$
$b2 - 10 > 0$
$a1 + a2 - 100 = 0$
$b1 + b2 - 80 = 0$
$a1 - 80 = 0$
$a2 - 20 = 0$
$a1*b2 - a2*b1 = 0$

Comment: In your example problem the last three constraints can be replaced by b1 - 4b2 = 0, so you are cooking with gas.

Comment: In your formulation, the last constraint is linear as mentioned by Igor Rivin. I'm sure you meant for $a_{1},a_{2}$ to be decision variables. Bilinear constraints look benign but in reality they are extremely nasty nonconvex constraints. However, there is a particular class of problems called "gasoline blending problems" that have been studied extensively and fits your your description. Bilinear constraints are also studied in global optimization. All this is to say: do not expect an easy answer to what you are asking.

Comment: You can either forgo a certificate of global optimality by solving this as an NLP, or you can try using NP-hard global optimization methods to solve this problem (using a free solver like Couenne). Alternatively, if you're willing to live with an approximation, you can model the bilinears within the range of interest with piecewise linear functions and model it as a Mixed Integer Program (MIP). RLT, if you've implemented it correctly, should give you a solution too. 

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. I would like to apologize for writing the problem so fast that I did not realize that it was indeed a LP. The real formulation is quite bigger, so my intention was only to illustrate the constraint I was talking about. What a pity I totally destroyed the problem doing it. :)

I have checked the RLT implementation and it gives a solution, although it is not very tight. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_1 x_2 - x_3 x_4 = 0$ is inherently nonlinear, and maybe more importantly non-convex: e.g. the midpoint of two feasible solutions may not be (in fact, hardly ever is) a feasible solution.  So in general there is no such thing as an equivalent formulation that is linear.  However, in special cases something might be possible.  In your example (ignoring $a_1 - 80 = 0$ and $a_2 - 20 = 0$ which make the problem trivial),  solve the constraints $a_1 + a_2 - 100 = 0$ and 
$b_1 + b_2 - 80 = 0$ for $a_2$ and $b_2$ and you get $a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1 =  80 a_1 - 100 b_1$ so this becomes a linear constraint.

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert. Unfortunately, in the real problem that I am trying to model it seems I cannot simplify the constraint like that. However, I think your answer is very informative, since I get the idea of my constraint being inherently non-linear. What really disturbs me is its non-convex nature. I am not really sure about the next steps. Should I try to turn it into a convex constraint, so I could apply a certain solver? Or should I go for checking optimality of the solution?